# date strtotime() calculation returns 1969 date

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code getting `$_POST` from HTML form:

```
<?php
$departureTime = date("l, Y-M-d H:i:s");
// calculate time-traveled time
$arrivalTime = date( "l, Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime(
        "$departureTime
        .' '
        .$travelTimeOperator        // '+' or '-'
        .$timeAmount            // integer or decimal (tested with integer)
        .' '
        .$travelTimeInterval") );   // 'days' or 'hours'

echo "$timeAmount, $departureTime, $arrivalTime";
?>
```

I get the following output, using `3` as my `$timeAmount`, `-` as my operator and `days` as `$travelTimeInterval`:

> 3, Friday, 2014-Oct-17 04:36:43, Wednesday, 1969-Dec-31 19:00:00

How can I fix the 1969 date? I've read [something](http://www.rachaelarnold.com/dev/archive/why-is-date-returning-wrong) about Unix timestamps but I can't get it to work. In this case it is intended to subtract 3 days. I get the exact same value `1969-Dec-31 19:00:00` if I try to add days instead.

*PS: I used line breaks in my concatenate to make it easier to troubleshoot, I realize it is not standard.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string supplied to `strtotime` is invalid. You started a double quote, but you didn't end it correctly:

```
    $departureTime = date("l, Y-M-d H:i:s");
$travelTimeOperator = '+';
$timeAmount = 1;
$travelTimeInterval = 'days';
$departureTimeString = "$departureTime
        .' '
        .$travelTimeOperator        // '+' or '-'
        .$timeAmount            // integer or decimal (tested with integer)
        .' '
        .$travelTimeInterval";
echo $departureTimeString;
// Friday, 2014-Oct-17 11:20:43 .' ' .+ // '+' or '-' .1 // integer or decimal (tested with integer) .' ' .days
```

You can do something like this to solve it:

```
<?php
$departureTime = date("l, Y-M-d H:i:s");

$travelTimeOperator = '+';
$timeAmount = 1;
$travelTimeInterval = 'days';
$departureTimeString = "$departureTime "
                       . $travelTimeOperator
                       . $timeAmount
                       . " $travelTimeInterval";
$arrivalTime = date( "l, Y-M-d H:i:s", strtotime($departureTimeString));

echo "$timeAmount, $departureTime, $arrivalTime";
// 1, Friday, 2014-Oct-17 11:22:23, Saturday, 2014-Oct-18 11:22:23
```

Using object oriented features, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$departureTime = new DateTimeImmutable();

$travelTimeOperator = '+';
$timeAmount = 1;
$travelTimeInterval = 'days';
$relativeDateString = "{$travelTimeOperator}{$timeAmount} $travelTimeInterval";
$arriveTime = $departureTime->modify($relativeDateString);

echo $arriveTime->format('l, Y-M-d H:i:s');
// Saturday, 2014-Oct-18 11:26:15
```

Comment: Well that's a nice answer! +1 and you should check out [codereview.se] :)

Answer (score 3):

your value in strtotime() cannot be interpreted as a valid date string by php.

When this happens, php uses the timestamp 0 which is 1970-1-1 00:00:00.
You subtract 5 hours (your timezone) from that date which gives you 1969-12-31 19:00:00.

try this:

```
$arrivalTime = date("l, Y-M-d H:i:s",
strtotime($travelTimeOperator . $timeAmount . ' ' .$travelTimeInterval));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are abusing strtotime for performing calculations on dates and times supplied as strings? Try the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class. It has a [modify](http://php.net/datetime.modify) method.

For example:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // now
$date->modify('+2 hours'); // add two hours
echo $date->format('l, Y-M-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Will that adapt OK to variables? Say instead of `('+2 hours')` I wrote `($travelTimeOperator.$timeAmount.' '.$travelTimeInterval)` or some such?

Comment: Yes, it would but don't forget to verify/filter what you are putting in `modify`. It will throw a warning and return `false` if the input is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $departureTime = date("l, Y-M-d H:i:s");
 if ($travelTimeInterval=='days') {$unit=(24*3600);} else {$unit=3600;}
 $diff=$travelTimeOperator.($unit*$timeAmount);
 $arrtime=time()+$diff;
 $arrivalTime = date( "l, Y-M-d H:i:s", $arrtime);
 echo "$timeAmount, $departureTime, $arrivalTime";
?>
```

This should do the trick if you dont want to change your programming method to object oriented.